# Remove noise on a wav file

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I'm working on a small code to learn signal processing on Matlab. I have got a .wav sound with some noise and I just want to remove the noise. I tried the code under but noise is not removed correctly. My idea is to do a cut band filter to remove the different noise components on the fft. After a lot of researches, I don't understant where is my problem. Here my code :

```
clear all;
clc;
close all;

% We load and plot the signal
[sig,Fs] = audioread('11.wav');

N = length(sig);

figure,plot(sig); title 'signal'

% FFT of the signal
fft_sig = abs(fft(sig)); 

% Normalisation of the frequencies for the plot
k = 0 : length(sig) - 1;  
f = k*Fs/length(sig);

plot(f,fft_sig);

% Loop with 2 elements because there are 2 amplitudes (not sure about
% this)
 for i = 1:2

% I put noise components in an array
[y(i),x(i)] = max(fft_sig);

% Normalisation of the frequencies to eliminate
f(i) =  x(i) * (Fs/N);

% Cut band filter with elimination of f from f-20 to f+20 Hz
b = fir1(2 , 2 * [f(i)-20 f(i)+20] / Fs, 'stop')

sig = filter(b,1,sig);

figure,plot(abs(fft(sig)));title 'fft of the signal'

end
```

Here the images I got, the fft plot is exactly the same before and after applying the filter, there is a modification only on the x axis :

[image]

[image]

[image]

The sampling frequency is Fs = 22050.

Thanks in advance for your help, I hope I'm clear enough in my description

Comment: try using 'freqz' to see what your filter looks like. you want to build a notch filter. if you have the dsp toolbox you can use 'iirnotch'

Comment: It might be an issue with your normalization. `fir1` expects units of rad/sec and you have not accounted for this anywhere. You can also discard the second half of the output of `fft` as it is just a mirror image of the first half (otherwise this may mess up your peak component detection scheme). Regarding your peak component detection, as it stands, your call to max(fft_sig) will return the same exact component every time whereas you need it to output the next largest component on every iteration.

Comment: And what is the most important - plot the magnitude in logarithmic scale!

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't explicitly said so, the code you provided essentially defines your *noise* as narrowband interference at two frequencies (even though that interference may look less 'noisy').

The first thing to notice is that the value `x(i)` obtained from `max(fft_sig)` corresponds to the *1-based* index of the located maximum. It won't make a huge difference for large `N`, but it may have an impact for smaller values especially when trying to design a very narrow notch filter. The corresponding frequency would then be:

```
freq =  (x(i)-1) * (Fs/N);
```

Also if you are going to iteratively attenuate frequency components you would need to update `fft_sig` which you use to pick the frequency components to be attenuated (otherwise you will always pick the same component). The simplest would be to recompute `fft_sig` from the filtered `sig`:

```
sig = filter(b,1,sig);
fft_sig = abs(fft(sig));
```

Finally, since you are trying to attenuate a very narrow frequency range, you may find that you need to increase the FIR filter order by a few orders of magnitudes to get a good attenuation at the desired frequency without attenuating everything else. As was pointed out in comments such a narrow notch filter can often be better implemented using an IIR filter.

The updated code would then look somewhat like:

```
% Loop with 2 elements because there are 2 amplitudes
for i = 1:2

  % I put noise components in an array
  % Limit peak search to the lower-half of the spectrum since the
  % upper half is symmetric
  [y(i),x(i)] = max(fft_sig(1:floor(N/2)+1));

  % Normalisation of the frequencies to eliminate
  freq =  (x(i)-1) * (Fs/N);

  % Cut band filter with elimination of f from f-20 to f+20 Hz
  b = fir1(2000 , 2 * [freq-20 freq+20] / Fs, 'stop')

  sig = filter(b,1,sig);
  fft_sig = abs(fft(sig));

  %figure;plot(f, abs(fft_sig));title 'fft of the signal'
  figure;plot(f, 20*log10(abs(fft_sig)));title 'fft of the signal'
end
```

As far as the last FFT plot showing a different x-axis, it is simply because you omitted to provide an x-axis variable (in occurrence `f` used in the previous plot), so the plot shows the array index (instead of frequencies) as the x-axis.